# How to show only one data in blade that coming from collection in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

im new at Laravel, so i have following problem:

I have db with issue table, that contains 15 names of diseases with it's description. This is my model

```
class Issue extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $guarded = false;

    public function gender() {
        return $this->belongsTo(BodyPart::class);
    }
}
```

And here's controller:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Issue;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke()
    {
        $eye_issues = Issue::all();
        return view('app.issues.man.eyes.index', compact('eye_issues'));
    }
}
```

And finally below my blade file:

```
<main>
    <section id="schedule" class="section-with-bg">

            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="100">
                @foreach($eye_issues as $issue)
                    @if($issue->body_part_id == 2 and $issue->gender_id == 1)
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#issue-{{ $issue->id }}" role="tab"
                               data-bs-toggle="tab">{{ $issue->issue }}</a>
                        </li>
                    @endif
                @endforeach
            </ul>

            <div class="tab-content row justify-content-center" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200">

                @foreach($eye_issues as $issue)
                    @if($issue->body_part_id == 2 and $issue->gender_id == 1)
                        <div role="tabpanel" class="col-lg-9 tab-pane fade show active" id="issue-{{ $issue->id }}">
                            <div class="row schedule-item justify-content-center">
                                <div class="col-md-10" style=text-align:center>
                                    <h4>{{ $issue->description }}</h4>
                                    <a href="{{ route('man.quiz-' . $issue->id) }}" class="button btn btn-primary">Test yourself</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    @endif
                @endforeach

            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
</main>
```

So problem is, after loading the page, navigation tabs should show all disease names (as it does) and the description section must be empty and show according description of disease that selected from nav-tabs and change description if disease is changed from nav-tabs. But after loading page, in the description section, there are all disease description, even nav-tabs selected to none onload. Only after selecting all diseases from nav-tabs, page works properly.

P.S I use MySQL if case u wanted to know. i tried to use all JS and CSS hide and show functions and other methods from internet, but no one works, and i guess it depends only on laravel it self. if you dont understand what i mean, comment it, i'll leave link for demo video of the issue

Comment: You're loading `Issue::all()`, but then looping and displaying only if `body_part_id == 2` and `gender_id == 1`. So why not `$eyeIssues = Issue::where('body_part_id', 2)->where('gender_id', 1)->get();`? Also, none of your `nav-item` or `nav-link` have the `active` class (one needs to by default), so nothing will display until you click one of them (since that is what assigns the `active` class)

Comment: Hello there! I got with backend part thks for that. but if i add ACTIVE class to my NAV items, all my navigational items are selecting as active, since im looping them

Comment: I know... I said you have to add `active` to ***ONE*** of them (*"one needs to by default"*). Don't hardcode `active` in your loop, do something like `class="{{ $loop->first ? 'nav-link active' : 'nav-link' }}"` Sidenote, `$loop` is available in all `@foreach()` loops (and others) in Laravel: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/blade#the-loop-variable

Comment: Bro, u cant even imagine how u helped me. thk u a lot brother)